# Как проверить нажата ли радио-кнопка JS

Tags: javascript

[image]

нужно проверить нажата ли определённая радио-кнопка

Comment: А как выглядит ваш html код? Должно работать. И что такое `i`? В общем, проверка `.checked` правильная, видимо с условием `i == 3` что-то не так.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick=(e)=>
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].matches(':checked'),
  document.querySelectorAll('input')[1].matches(':checked'));
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="x"/><input type="radio" name="x"/><button>Check</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример на JS [отсюда](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_checked.asp)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var coffee = document.getElementsByName("coffee");
  var txt = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < coffee.length; i++) {
    if (coffee[i].checked) {
      txt = txt + coffee[i].value + " ";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("order").value = "You ordered a coffee with: " + txt;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="coffee" value="cream">With cream<br>
<input type="radio" name="coffee" value="sugar">With sugar<br>

<input type="text" id="order" size="50">
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Send order">
```